# Undetectable BLE GATT Server Nexus 9

Tags: android, bluetooth, server, gatt

I am developing an application which is a bluetooth chat. I use BluetoothLE in my application. I open the GATT server on Nexus 9  but other devices can not find me. But if  I try to connect the device directly to the `connect("B4:CE:F6:B6:75:16")` connection takes place.

This is my method for start server:

```
private void createServiceWithCharacteristics() {
if (bluetoothLeAdvertiser != null && bluetoothAdapter != null) {

    mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, mGattServerCallback);

    BluetoothGattService ias = new BluetoothGattService(
            GattAttributes.getServiceUuid(),
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    notifyCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.CHARACTERISTIC_BLUETOOTH_APP_MESSAGE_NOTIFY),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
    notifyCharacteristic.addDescriptor(new BluetoothGattDescriptor(GattAttributes.CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE));

    messageCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.CHARACTERISTIC_BLUETOOTH_APP_MESSAGE_READ),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    messageCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);

    connectionExtendedCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.CHARACTERISTIC_BLUETOOTH_APP_IS_CONNECTION_EXTENDED),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    connectionExtendedCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);

    ias.addCharacteristic(notifyCharacteristic);
    ias.addCharacteristic(messageCharacteristic);
    ias.addCharacteristic(connectionExtendedCharacteristic);
    mGattServer.addService(ias);
}
```

}